# Grails: how to "access" a domain class instance variables across other domains?

Tags: grails

Sorry, I could not come up with a better title for this question, but gave my best shot. I have domain classes `User` and `Post` -- a `user` has many `posts`, and a `post` belongs to a user, as follows.

```
class User {

    String name

    static hasMany = [ posts : Post ]

    static constraints = {  }
}

class Post {

    String content

    static belongsTo = [ user : User ]

    static constraints = {  }
}
```

I have another domain class `Status` as follows.

```
class Status {
    Boolean isActive

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Each `user` and `post` has a `status`, and I am wondering how to implement that? Couple of different approaches I can think of doing this are:

1. Inheritance: Let `User` and `Post` extend `Status`, and use `static mapping = { tablePerHierarchy false }` in the `Status`. Then `User` and `Post` automatically inherit the instance variables of `Status` (and they get persisted in separate tables). However this approach does not seem appropriate as `User` and `Post` are not actually a `Status`.
2. I can redefine the `Status` instance variables in `User` and `Post`, and then do something like this in `User` and `Post`

```
    static constraints = {
        importFrom Status

        // other constraints 
    }
```

**Questions:**

- Is one approach better than the other?
- Is there a better way of achieving this?
- Is there a best practices that Grails pros can recommend?

Note: The `Status` domain has many instance variables (what is presented here is a stripped down version), and I need to "access" its instance variables from many other domains (`User`, `Post`, and many other). Otherwise I could have just gotten ride of the `Status` domain and just define those instance variables in `User` and `Post` separately. The approach 2 mentioned above kind of does this, except that it saves re-typing the constraints by just using `importFrom Status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that Inheritance is not a clean option. Your second approach seems right but why do you need the "importFrom"? By defining Status as an instance variable in User and Post, Status will take care of the validation of its own variables. You can still access Status' instance variables from Post/User as like this:

```
user.status.isActive
```

Comment: Thank you, Rami. Actually I meant including `Boolean isActive` instead of `Status status` in both `User` and `Post`. In that case I needed the `importFrom Status` to take care of the constraints. But I think I understand what you mean. Although, if I declared `Status status` in both `User` and `Post`, and do `def user = new User(name: "my name", status: new Status(isActive: true))` and `user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)`, the code fails saying something like `NULL not allowed for column "STATUS_ID"`! So I am definitely missing something. Any clarification would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I had to save the status explicitly `status.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)` before saving the user `user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)`, and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Also if you are new to Grails then I recommend reading a bit about cascading and ownership in relationships. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Actually, yup I am a newbie, and have been following the Grails in Action MEAP, 2nd Edn, plus a bit here and there from http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide. However, if you have any specific reference in mind, I would love to know. Thank you!

Comment: Grails in Action is my best reference in addition to the official docs. Also subscribing to the Grails dev mailing list is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, Rami. I also subscribed to the mailing list @codehaus.org.